# How to manually verify signatures on x509 certificates in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, x509

I have two X509Certificate objects x1(root) and x2 in `.pem` format.

I want to verify that x2 was signed by x1 manually.

How to exactly do this in Flutter/Dart?

I found this [article](https://medium.com/@ebuschini/a-journey-into-verifying-signatures-on-x-509-certificates-168a5bafaa14), but all operations there is done in terminal with `openssl` and at some stage there is need to convert `.pem` to `.der` for extracting of signature from the certificate.

Also i know that C# have such [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_X509Certificates_X509Certificate2_Verify)for verifying and i cannot find any analog in the flutter/dart

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing this using [x509b](https://pub.dev/packages/x509b) package from pub.dev. The original x509 package is seemingly not updated anymore and uses an outdated version of asn1lib. In my version I am using both x509 and asn1lib itself. Pretty sure there are cleaner/more performant ways, but this does the trick for me.

I also use the extracted public key from my root certificate directly instead of using the entire certificate, but I am sure you can also do that step with these libraries.

The tbsCertificate property from x509 library seems wrong, so I extract the TBS Certificate part manually using ASN1Parser.

The decodePEM function was taken from the example in [asn1lib](https://github.com/wstrange/asn1lib/blob/master/example/main.dart) repo.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:x509b/x509.dart' as x509;
import 'package:asn1lib/asn1lib.dart';

bool verifyCertificate() {
    var strX1PublicKeyInfo = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nSOME PUBLIC KEY\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
    var strX2Certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nSOME CERTIFICATE\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    var x1PublicKey = (x509.parsePem(strX1PublicKeyInfo).single as x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo).subjectPublicKey as x509.RsaPublicKey;
    var x2Certificate = x509.parsePem(strX2Certificate).single as x509.X509Certificate;
    var x2CertificateDER = decodePEM(strX2Certificate);

    var asn1Parser = ASN1Parser(x2CertificateDER);
    var seq = asn1Parser.nextObject() as ASN1Sequence;
    var tbsSequence = seq.elements[0] as ASN1Sequence;

    var signature = x509.Signature(Uint8List.fromList(x2Certificate.signatureValue!));
    var verifier = x1PublicKey.createVerifier(x509.algorithms.signing.rsa.sha256);

    return verifier.verify(tbsSequence.encodedBytes, signature)
}

Uint8List decodePEM(pem) {
  var startsWith = [
    '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----',
    '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----',
    '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----',
  ];
  var endsWith = [
    '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----',
    '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----',
    '-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
  ];

  //HACK
  for (var s in startsWith) {
    if (pem.startsWith(s)) pem = pem.substring(s.length);
  }

  for (var s in endsWith) {
    if (pem.endsWith(s)) pem = pem.substring(0, pem.length - s.length);
  }

  //Dart base64 decoder does not support line breaks
  pem = pem.replaceAll('\n', '');
  pem = pem.replaceAll('\r', '');
  return Uint8List.fromList(base64.decode(pem));
}
```

Comment: It is rather unfortunate we are still in a state of "roll your own" with Dart here.

Comment: I needed extra effort to make this work. In the certificates I'm working with, the `signatureValue` is [ASN1 DER encoded](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/57731/ecdsa-signature-rs-to-asn1-der-encoding-question), and could not be used as-is with the verifier, which was expecting (r, s) to be raw concatenated integer representation.